# Is OnChange required for react forms anymore?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

This is only a theoretical question about react.

I'm currently learning ReactJS and it's quite nice, but I'm confused about this and would love to get a response.

In every tutorial that I find online (most of them are years old and I'm using React 16.8 which should be the latest version), everybody states that it is important to use `onChange` when creating a form component. In these tutorials you aren't able to type anything inside the form if you don't have an `onChange` event.

The thing I find strange is that I can enter text and everything works fine right now without using any `onChange` event.

My questions are these:

- Is it still mandatory?
- Is it good practice to use it?
- Should I ignore it and code without it?

Comment: It's required if you want to react to the typed input. React by default uses one-way binding.

Comment: There's no way to answer this without understanding what the actual code is. If you have a `value` property in a form field then it would need to be updated on any changes. Whether or not you need a `value` property depends on usage. This is all discussed in the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html, https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the pragmatic answer is that `onChange` is not required, but considered a best practice. Maintaining the form state with React creates a single source of truth and helps later when validations are needed.

Check out the React docs on controlled components:

> In HTML, form elements such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` typically maintain their own state and update it based on user input. In React, mutable state is typically kept in the state property of components, and only updated with `setState()`.
>
> We can combine the two by making the React state be the “single source of truth”. Then the React component that renders a form also controls what happens in that form on subsequent user input. An input form element whose value is controlled by React in this way is called a “controlled component”.

[Controlled Components Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)